# Is using std::find and C::insert() thread safe if iterators are not invalidated by insert

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have a container C whose iterators are not invalidated upon C.insert(), can I safely perform a std::find() on the container while a concurrent insert() is being performed? That is, am I guaranteed to find a matching element or C::end(), ignoring the fact that the inserted element may match but std::find() gives me C::end()?

Comment: C++ containers are not thread-safe for concurrent reads and writes.

Comment: If the container is from the standard library, it is not thread safe.  If any thread is modifying it, no other thread may safely access it.

Comment: invalidating iterators and having thread-safe state aren't related.   The answer is that it is by no means guaranteed to be legal.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Why are you answering in the comments section?

Answer (score 2):

No. Although iterators are not invalidated by your mutating operation, it is still a mutating operation, and none of the standard containers are defined to be safe to read in one thread while a mutating operation is taking place in another. Remember that there are still "innards" to your container, all manner of internal state, which may be involved in both operations.

Comment: Exactly.  All that's guaranteed by an insert that doesn't invalidate iterators is that by the END of the insert call it's valid to continue iterating on it.

Comment: Thanks. This was my prior but I couldn't find the wording in the standard that defined what "not invalidating an iterator" really means.

Comment: @MichaelConlen It means exactly what it says, and nothing else